# Count() en php para sacar la longitud

Tags: php, array

Resulta que tengo los siguientes arreglos asociativos:

```
Array ( 
    [ItemID] => 192 
    [ItemName] => Ford 
    [IMEI] => 0080WEWE 
    [Status] => A 
)
```

cuando uso el método count() para ese array el resultado es 4, porque cuenta los elementos.

Ahora tengo el siguiente array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
           [ItemID] => 173
           [ItemName] => Cheyene 
           [IMEI] => 207729471 
           [Status] => A
         )
   [1] => Array (
           [ItemID] => 191
           [ItemName] => Vento  
           [IMEI] => 008045840 
           [Status] => A 
         )
)
```

cuando saco el la longitud de este array con el método count() el resultado es 2.

Ahora la pregunta es como pudiera hacerle para que el arreglo 1, me diera como resultado 1 usando count() o como puedo saber si mi arreglo es un arreglo de arreglos o solo un arreglo común obviamente asociativo?

Comment: Uhm, son varias preguntas :o Qué es lo que realmente necesitas saber?

Answer (score 2):

Usando exclusivamente count creo que es imposible, tocaría mínimo con un if y comparando la versión recursiva de count vs el conteo típico:

```
if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo count($array);
}
```